# Is there a gfortran option for prefetch?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, prefetch

I would like to use prefetch in my code to improve cache behavior. For example, assume I have this array of indexes: `indexes = [9,3,2,6,7,5,8,4,1,10]` and the code below:

```
do i=1,10:
   total = total + arr(indexes(i)) * i
end do
```

So the cache behavior of indexes is good while the one of arr is bad.
An example of what I want will be:

```
do i=1,10:
   prefetch(arr(indexes(i+1)))
   total = total + arr(indexes(i)) * i
end do
```

I've seen this: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/o-to-p/prefetch-and-noprefetch.html but I was looking for a version for `gfortran` too, or better: compiler independent.

Comment: Without a complete MWE to play with and given the rather small loop stop value, you probably want to use `-funroll-loops` and `-O3`.

Comment: This is just a toy example to demonstrate the need. My real case involves a huge loop so I would like to manually prefetch.

Comment: Sounds like a famous Knuth quote about premature optimization.   gfortran is part of GCC, which has a `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` option.  The description does state: _This option may generate better or worse code; results are highly dependent on the structure of loops within the source code._   I'll recommend that you compile with `-fopt-info -O3 -funroll-loops` and check the produced information.

Answer (score 0):

That loop is so short it will most likely be fully optimized out if you use any decent level of compiler optimization. Anyways, I think everything depends on the nature of your `indexes` array. As a rule of thumb:

- does `indexes` change often, seldom, at all?

If it never changes:

- Make it a `parameter`
- Also make the multiplier a parameter: `integer, parameter :: fixed_i(*) = [(i,i=1,10)]

So the compiler will have all the information at compile time.
If not that often, you should consider to pre-process it to at least some extent. I would at least

- Make a temporary array `tmp_i = [(i,i=1,10)]`; sort `indexes` in ascending order, (and `tmp_i` accordingly)

Comment: how does tmp_i help my cache behavior?

Comment: if you sort `indexes_i`, then the multiplication `indexes(i)*i` is not valid anymore unless you make `i` an array and sort it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific real conditions, I would try manually pre-fetching. Basically, assign a new array using the indexed order:

```
! -- Manual prefetch, ideally done once
do i=1,10
   indexed(i) = arr(indexes(i))
end do

! -- Use cached data
do i=1,10
   total = total + indexed(i) * i
end do
```

In my *opinion*, this work better when:

- There are not too many `indexes` arrays
- Each `indexes` array is used relatively frequently
- memory usage is not a bottleneck

I doubt there is a compiler-independent solution to this in the compile options.

Comment: How can I make sure `indexed` is not optimized out?

Comment: In my example, `indexed` would ideally be set once somewhere during initialization and then stored. It would be accessed later (`use cached data`) multiple times.